# Is it correct to dynamically add rows to a table (in sqlite), or should I use csv?

Tags: sqlite, csv

Just like when adding a new contact in the ios contact app, (like [this](http://postimg.org/image/oqfsbjybd/)) you can add multiple phone numbers, and it doesn't know how many there will be, so therefore they don't know how many rows they should initially add in the table of `sqlite`.

So how does that work, do they dynamically add rows to the table, or do they use csv?

(I'm using objective c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one table for the contacts:

```
CREATE TABLE contacts(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(50)
);
```

and you link multiple rows in a separate table to the contacts

```
CREATE TABLE phone_numbers(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    phone_number VARCHAR(15),
    contact_id INTEGER REFERENCES contacts(id)
);
```

When you create a contact, you add a row to contacts. When you add a phone number, you add it to phone numbers and refer to the row in contacts. You can add as many rows as you want to phone numbers for the same contact.

Comment: Is it fine if there are multiple rows in `contact` called `name`?

Comment: I think you misunderstand. The table contacts has a column called "name". Each row in contacts has a value for the column "name".

Comment: Also, I know this is off topic of my question, so if you don't wanna answer it,  feel free not to, cuz u already answered my posted question :). I will be having a lot of text, like a couple paragraphs. Is it sufficient, or regular to store that all in 1 row?

Comment: If your row is for a single contact, and all the text you are putting in relates to that contact, then you should put it all in one row.

Comment: Also, when I add the values to `phone_numbers` should `contact_id` be a null, or should I leave it empty?

Comment: So there will be multiple rows called `phone_number`, write?